# Redux: assigning useDispatch to a variable causing component to go blank

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a very weird problem. I didn't use React Redux for a while and now I'm back to it. The problem is, when I assign useDispatch() to a variable, the whole component goes blank. I checked it with another component and there's the same problem. Never met with issue like this. Do anyone had this problem before or know what's going on?

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

export const LoginUser = ({ setShowLoginPopup }: Props) => {
  const [emailValue, setEmailValue] = useState("");
  const [passwordValue, setPasswordValue] = useState("");
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <Container>
      <Content>
       {...}
        <ConfirmButton
          onClick={() =>
            axios
              .post("https://localhost:44390/api/user/register", {
                email: emailValue,
                password: passwordValue,
              })
              .then((res) => {
                localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.token);
                dispatch(login(res.data));
              })
          }
        >
          LOG IN
        </ConfirmButton>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you show me your react and react-redux version?

Comment: "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.1",

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. Have you ever logged your dispatch variable? What is the value?

Comment: If I try to use useDispatch() without assigning it to variable - same happens, component goes blank. I checked redux dev tools and there is no even my redux state.

Comment: Can you show me your login function being used in dispatch?

Comment: And const dispatch = useDispatch(); console.log(dispatch); then please show me dispatch value.

Comment: Everything is clear now.. I've never checked console. There were a lot of errors saying I didn't wrap my app in Provider. My bad, sorry and thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm glad to hear you solve your problems - : )